# I am unable to do manual play and pause

Tags: javascript

```js
console.log(" Tic Tac Toe");
let music = new Audio("/tic tac toe/tic tac toe/music.mp3");
let audioTurn = new Audio("/tic tac toe/tic tac toe/ting.mp3");
let gameover = new Audio("/tic tac toe/tic tac toe/gameover.mp3");
let turn = "X";
let isgameover = false;
let button = document.getElementsByClassName('play');


// music.play();
// Function to change the Turn...
const changeTurn = ()=>{
    return turn === "X"? "0": "X";
}

// Function to check for a win...
const checkWin = ()=>{
    let boxtext = document.getElementsByClassName('boxtext');
    let wins = [
        [0, 1, 2, 5, 5, 0],
        [3, 4, 5, 5, 15, 0],
        [6, 7, 8, 5, 25, 0],
        [0, 3, 6, -5, 15, 90],
        [1, 4, 7, 5, 15, 90],
        [2, 5, 8, 15, 15, 90],
        [0, 4, 8, 5, 15, 45],
        [2, 4, 6, 5, 15, 135],
    ]
    wins.forEach(e =>{
        if((boxtext[e[0]].innerText === boxtext[e[1]].innerText) && (boxtext[e[2]].innerText === boxtext[e[1]].innerText) && (boxtext[e[0]].innerText !== "") ){
            document.querySelector('.info').innerText = boxtext[e[0]].innerText + " Won"
            isgameover = true
            document.querySelector('.imgbox').getElementsByTagName('img')[0].style.width = "200px";
            document.querySelector(".line").style.transform = `translate(${e[3]}vw, ${e[4]}vw) rotate(${e[5]}deg)`
            document.querySelector(".line").style.width = "20vw";
        }
    })
}

// music.play();
// Game Logic...
let boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
Array.from(boxes).forEach(element =>{
    let boxtext = element.querySelector('.boxtext');
    element.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        if(boxtext.innerText === ''){
            boxtext.innerText = turn;
            turn = changeTurn();
            audioTurn.play();
            checkWin();
            if (!isgameover){
                document.getElementsByClassName("info")[0].innerText  = "Turn for " + turn;
            } 
        }
    })
})

// Add onclick listener to Reset Button...
reset.addEventListener('click' , ()=>{
    let boxtexts = document.querySelectorAll('.boxtext');
    Array.from(boxtexts).forEach(element => {
        element.innerText = ""
    });
    turn = "X";
    isgameover = false
    document.querySelector(".line").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementsByClassName("info")[0].innerText  = "Turn for " + turn;
    document.querySelector('.imgbox').getElementsByTagName('img')[0].style.width = "0px"
    }
)

// For handling the music play....
button.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    if(music.paused){
        music.play();
        button.classList.remove("fa-play-circle");
        button.classList.add("fa-pause-circle");
    }
    else{
        music.pause();
        button.classList.add("fa-play-circle");
        button.classList.remove("fa-pause-circle"); 
    }
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Baloo+Bhaina+2&display=swap');
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav{
    background-color: #a60776;
    color: white;
    height: 65px;
    font-size: 27px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 12px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

nav ul{
    list-style: none;
}

.gameContainer{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 10vw);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 10vw);
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    position: relative;
}

.box{
    border: 2px solid black;
    font-size: 8vw;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.box:hover{
    background-color: rgb(249, 226, 249);
}

.info{
    font-size: 22px;
}

.gameInfo{
    padding: 0 34px;
    font-family: 'Baloo Bhaina 2', cursive;
}

.gameInfo h1{
    font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.imgbox img{
    width: 0;
    transition: width 0.7s ease-in-out;
}

.br-0{
    border-right: 0;
}

.bl-0{
    border-left: 0;
}
.bt-0{
    border-top: 0;
}
.bb-0{
    border-bottom: 0;
}

#reset{
    margin: 0 23px;
    padding: 6px 14px;
    background-color: #fbddfb;
    border-radius: 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: 'Baloo Bhaina 2';
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

.buttons{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.play{
    margin: 0 0 0 2rem;
}

.line{
    background-color: black;
    height: 3px;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #911d91;
    transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 950px) {
    .gameContainer{
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .gameInfo{
        margin-top: 34px;
    }
    .gameInfo h1{
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }
    .container{
        grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 20vw);
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 20vw);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Tic-Tac-Toe</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>MyTicTacToe.com</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="gameContainer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="line"></div>
            <div class="box bt-0 bl-0"><span class="boxtext"></span></div>
            <div class="box bt-0"><span class="boxtext"></span></div>
            <div class="box bt-0 br-0"><span class="boxtext"></span></div>
            <div class="box bl-0"><span class="boxtext"></span></div>
            <div class="box"><span class="boxtext"></span></div>
            <div class="box br-0"><span class="boxtext"></span></div>
            <div class="box bb-0 bl-0"><span class="boxtext"></span></div>
            <div class="box bb-0"><span class="boxtext"></span></div>
            <div class="box bb-0 br-0"><span class="boxtext"></span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="gameInfo">
            <h1>Welcome to Tic Tac Toe</h1>
            <div class="buttons">
                <span class="info">Turn for X</span>
                <button id="reset">Reset</button>
                <i class="play fas fa-4x fa-circle-play"></i>
                <!-- <i class="play fa-solid fa-circle-pause"></i>          -->
            </div>
            
        <div class="imgbox">
            <img src="/tic tac toe/tic tac toe/excited.gif" alt="excited">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a90b59c65b.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the problem code.

```
// For handling the music play....
button.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    if(music.paused){
        music.play();`enter code here`
        button.classList.remove("fa-play-circle");
        button.classList.add("fa-pause-circle");
    }
    else{
        music.pause();
        button.classList.add("fa-play-circle");
        button.classList.remove("fa-pause-circle"); 
    }
});
```

I just want to make this button working.
if I click on the button the music will play and when I  want to pause just click and pause the music.
please help me and solve my issue please.
please solve my problem
I am student first year.
I am in computer science and Engineering branch
help me I am new to the javascript coding arrives this problem while coding
but give solution to and help me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This (*your* code) looks like it should work.

```js
let music = new Audio("https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Kalimba.mp3");

function toggle_play() {
  if (music.paused) {
    music.play()
  } else {
    music.pause()

    // optional:
    //music.currentTime = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggle_play()">play/pause</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<script>
        var playbutton = document.getElementById("play");
        var pausebutton = document.getElementById("pause");
         
        function play() {
            playbutton.play();
        }
        function pause() {
            pausebutton.pause();
        }
    </script>
```

Split up the pause and play buttons so you can test each method.

Its a modified version of code here, [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-dom-audio-pause-method/#:~:text=The%20HTML%20DOM%20Audio%20pause,etc%2C%20attached%20on%20the%20audio](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-dom-audio-pause-method/#:%7E:text=The%20HTML%20DOM%20Audio%20pause,etc%2C%20attached%20on%20the%20audio).

CHeck out that link. It might have some helpful stuff for this issue if that code does not help.

Answer (score 0):

I understand my mistake , and got the solution of my problem.
here is the solution...

```
playbutton.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    if(music.paused || music.currentTime <=0){
        music.play();
        playbutton.classList.remove("fa-play-circle");
        playbutton.classList.add("fa-pause-circle");
    } else {
        music.pause();
        playbutton.classList.remove("fa-pause-circle");
        playbutton.classList.add("fa-play-circle");
    }
});
```

Now the music and the button changing is fully working with this code

```js
console.log(" Tic Tac Toe");
let music = new Audio("/tic tac toe/tic tac toe/music.mp3");
let audioTurn = new Audio("/tic tac toe/tic tac toe/ting.mp3");
let gameover = new Audio("/tic tac toe/tic tac toe/gameover.mp3");
let turn = "X";
let isgameover = false;
let playbutton = document.getElementById('play');
// let pausebutton = document.getElementsByClassName('fas fa-4x fa-circle-pause');
    
// function play(){
//     playbutton.play();
// }
// function pause(){
//     pausebutton.pause();
// }

// For handling the music play....
// function toggleplay(e){
//     if(e == music.paused){
//         music.play();

//     }
//     else {
//         music.pause();
//         playbutton.innerHTML = "fa-circle-play";
//     }
// }

// Code for background Music...
playbutton.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    if(music.paused || music.currentTime <=0){
        music.play();
        playbutton.classList.remove("fa-play-circle");
        playbutton.classList.add("fa-pause-circle");
    } else {
        music.pause();
        playbutton.classList.remove("fa-pause-circle");
        playbutton.classList.add("fa-play-circle");
    }
});

// music.play();
// Function to change the Turn...
const changeTurn = ()=>{
    return turn === "X"? "0": "X";
}

// Function to check for a win...
const checkWin = ()=>{
    let boxtext = document.getElementsByClassName('boxtext');
    let wins = [
        [0, 1, 2, 5, 5, 0],
        [3, 4, 5, 5, 15, 0],
        [6, 7, 8, 5, 25, 0],
        [0, 3, 6, -5, 15, 90],
        [1, 4, 7, 5, 15, 90],
        [2, 5, 8, 15, 15, 90],
        [0, 4, 8, 5, 15, 45],
        [2, 4, 6, 5, 15, 135],
    ]
    wins.forEach(e =>{
        if((boxtext[e[0]].innerText === boxtext[e[1]].innerText) && (boxtext[e[2]].innerText === boxtext[e[1]].innerText) && (boxtext[e[0]].innerText !== "") ){
            document.querySelector('.info').innerText = boxtext[e[0]].innerText + " Won"
            isgameover = true
            document.querySelector('.imgbox').getElementsByTagName('img')[0].style.width = "200px";
            document.querySelector(".line").style.transform = `translate(${e[3]}vw, ${e[4]}vw) rotate(${e[5]}deg)`
            document.querySelector(".line").style.width = "20vw";
        }
    })
}

// music.play();
// Game Logic...
let boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
Array.from(boxes).forEach(element =>{
    let boxtext = element.querySelector('.boxtext');
    element.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        if(boxtext.innerText === ''){
            boxtext.innerText = turn;
            turn = changeTurn();
            audioTurn.play();
            checkWin();
            if (!isgameover){
                document.getElementsByClassName("info")[0].innerText  = "Turn for " + turn;
            } 
        }
    })
})

// Add onclick listener to Reset Button...
reset.addEventListener('click' , ()=>{
    let boxtexts = document.querySelectorAll('.boxtext');
    Array.from(boxtexts).forEach(element => {
        element.innerText = ""
    });
    turn = "X";
    isgameover = false
    document.querySelector(".line").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementsByClassName("info")[0].innerText  = "Turn for " + turn;
    document.querySelector('.imgbox').getElementsByTagName('img')[0].style.width = "0px"
    }
)
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Baloo+Bhaina+2&display=swap');
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav{
    background-color: #a60776;
    color: white;
    height: 65px;
    font-size: 27px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 12px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

nav ul{
    list-style: none;
}

.gameContainer{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 10vw);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 10vw);
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    position: relative;
}

.box{
    border: 2px solid black;
    font-size: 8vw;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.box:hover{
    background-color: rgb(249, 226, 249);
}

.info{
    font-size: 22px;
}

.gameInfo{
    padding: 0 34px;
    font-family: 'Baloo Bhaina 2', cursive;
}

.gameInfo h1{
    font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.imgbox img{
    width: 0;
    transition: width 0.7s ease-in-out;
}

.br-0{
    border-right: 0;
}

.bl-0{
    border-left: 0;
}
.bt-0{
    border-top: 0;
}
.bb-0{
    border-bottom: 0;
}

#reset{
    margin: 0 23px;
    padding: 6px 14px;
    background-color: #fbddfb;
    border-radius: 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: 'Baloo Bhaina 2';
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

.buttons{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.button{
    margin: 0 0 0 2rem;
}

.line{
    background-color: black;
    height: 3px;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #911d91;
    transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 950px) {
    .gameContainer{
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .gameInfo{
        margin-top: 34px;
    }
    .gameInfo h1{
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }
    .container{
        grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 20vw);
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 20vw);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Tic-Tac-Toe</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>MyTicTacToe.com</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="gameContainer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="line"></div>
            <div class="box bt-0 bl-0"><span class="boxtext"></span></div>
            <div class="box bt-0"><span class="boxtext"></span></div>
            <div class="box bt-0 br-0"><span class="boxtext"></span></div>
            <div class="box bl-0"><span class="boxtext"></span></div>
            <div class="box"><span class="boxtext"></span></div>
            <div class="box br-0"><span class="boxtext"></span></div>
            <div class="box bb-0 bl-0"><span class="boxtext"></span></div>
            <div class="box bb-0"><span class="boxtext"></span></div>
            <div class="box bb-0 br-0"><span class="boxtext"></span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="gameInfo">
            <h1>Welcome to Tic Tac Toe</h1>
            <div class="buttons">
                <span class="info">Turn for X</span>
                <button id="reset">Reset</button>
                <i class="button fas fa-4x fa-play-circle" id="play"></i>
                <!-- <i class="button fas fa-4x fa-circle-pause" id="pause"></i>          -->
            </div>
            
        <div class="imgbox">
            <img src="/tic tac toe/tic tac toe/excited.gif" alt="excited">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a90b59c65b.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

...
please check above code.